# Open selected version of MS Office using Interop

Tags: c#, interop, ms-office

I installed both MS-Office 2007 and MS-Office 2010 and using Interop to interact with them:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
app = new Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
```

Is there any way I can specify which MS-Office version will be opened? In example: when users select version 2007 or version 2010 from a list, the application will open corresponding version?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try to dynamically resolve reference binding to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` assembly of appropriate version.

Comment: No matter what assembly version I use, it always opens MS-Office 2007. Can you explain your idea a little more, please?